# When displaying a list of select options that may change in the future, should I hardcode them in the UI or fetch from my database?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, reactjs

Let's say I am creating a UI where a user can pick their favorite Pokemon: Bulbasaur, Squirtle, Charmander, etc.

In my database I have a lookup table of the possible options:

```
pokemon
---
id name
1  Bulbasaur
2  Squirtle
3  Charmander
...
```

In my UI, should I fetch this list every time or simply hardcode it so users can select from it? In UIs, things like this look like they appear instantly, but wouldn't it better for data integrity/consistency if in the of adding more options, you only just update it in one place (the database) instead of worrying about also updating the UI?

Comment: If you know you're going to be adding more Pokemon, then fetch them from the database rather than hardcoding.

Comment: You can probably reduce the number of database access by doing proper caching. There are many caching options, and if you can let us know the update frequency, the UI, etc., perhaps we can suggest a sensible solution. Also, the strategy could be different if it were a web app, mobile app, or a desktop app, etc.

Comment: @Colin Will most likely be adding more Pokemon because new ones are being created every couple of years!

Comment: @TheLyrist Good point, I will implement caching e.g. Redis/Memcached for things like this. The update frequency would be "whenever someone decides they want to change their new favorite Pokemon" and the UI is just a section in a user profile > click edit button > show list of options > select and save. Curious why the strategy would be different depending on what kind of app? It's a mobile app btw.

Comment: @kayla sorry I am not familiar with mobile dev, so please excuse me if I am not making any sense. For web, depending on your expected update frequency, you can use different cache expiration setting, use a CDN, etc. For mobile and desktop, I assume there will be more local caching options? I think many mobile apps checks for updated material at launch only, and store the list locally etc?

Answer (score 3):

If you know you're going to be adding more Pokemon, then I would suggest fetching them from the database rather than hardcoding.

Think about if they were hardcoded – every time you wanted to add more Pokemon you'd have to push a new version of the code to your users.

However, if you have the frontend fetching the data from e.g. an API, then you can update and add more options without editing the frontend.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is depending on your implementation. If you are creating a very small (very small) application then you can store your options on UI side. In all other cases, it much better to fetch them from API.